# how to get all permutations of strings in an array list by specified size

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get all permutations of strings(words) in a java array list with two words.Following is the code i  tried but i am not getting all permutations of words in the list.

```
for (int y = 0; y<newList.size(); y++){

      String first = newList.get(y);
      String second = "";

      if(y+1<newList.size()){
        second = newList.get(y+1);
      }

      ArrayList<String> tmpArr = new ArrayList<String>();
      tmpArr.add(first);
      tmpArr.add(second);

      ArrayList<String> retArray = combine(tmpArr);
      for (int c = 0; c <retArray.size(); c++) {
        System.out.println(retArray.get(c));
      }                 
}

public static ArrayList<String> combine(ArrayList<String> arr){
        ArrayList<String> retArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(arr.size()==0){
            retArr.add("");
            return retArr;
        }
        ArrayList<String> tmpArr = (ArrayList<String>)arr.clone();
        tmpArr.remove(0);

        for(String str1 : combine(tmpArr)){
            for(String str2 : arr){
                retArr.add(str2+","+str1);
                if(retArr.size() == 10)
                    return retArr;
            }

        }
        return retArr;
}
```

Please let me know how to correct the code to get all permutations of words in the list with size 2(all permutations of words with two words as output)

For example if the input data is as follows
Input - [visit,party,delegation]

Expected Output - 
[visit,party
visit,delegation
party,visit
party,delegation
delegation,visit
delegation,party]

Current Output - 
[visit,party,
party,party,
party,delegation,
delegation,delegation,]

Comment: please post us the problems you are facing (errors, exceptions) and if not the current output what you are getting

Comment: The `if` statement in your `for` loop should be a loop from `y+1` through the end of the list.  I've posted simple code in an answer.

Comment: Whoops, misread your expected output.  Modified my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the two-word permutations of a list of words.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("party","visit","delegation");

for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < strings.size(); j++){
    if (i != j) System.out.println(strings.get(i) + "," + strings.get(j));
  }
}
```

EDIT:  added the if statement and changed the loop since you wanted permutations of different orders as well.

Comment: Do you consider: delegation, delegation a permutation?

Comment: Based on OP's expected output, no.

Answer (score 0):

You should step through your program with a debugger to see what happens.

My suggestion for the fault reason is: you create a new retArr in every call of combine, so you get only the results of the last call.

See that you use the same retArr for all executions of combine.